# MariaDB Syntax for Insert On Duplicate Update OR using CASE

Tags: php, syntax, mariadb, unique-constraint

I would like to fingerprint a device, and store the result alongside the Session Id in MariaDb.  I am writing in PHP, using the PDO Driver.  I generate a print client-side on the visited page, and POST an XHR to storePrint.php  I would like to update existing records OR insert a new one if they don't exist. Below is a snippet of the source code.  The print may already exist with a different session id, and the print may change without the session changing.  I would like to update the print, sessionId, and lastVisited timestamp (which I'm using decimal 14,4 and microtime(true) for that so not truly a timestamp but that is another tangent.

```
storePrint.php:

require_once('./library.php');
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    $_POST = sanitize($_POST); // Clean up input.
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $print = $_POST['clientPrint']; // max length = 32 characters
    $sId = $_POST['sessionId']; // max-length = 64 characters
    updatePrint($sId,$print,$from);
}
```

```
library.php:

    function updatePrint($id,$print,$from)
    {
        $now = microtime(true);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO prints (print,sessionId,lastUpdated) VALUES (:print,:sid,:lastC) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE print=:print, sessionId = :sId, lastUpdated = :lastV";

        $import = [":print" => $print,":sid" => $id,
        ":lastC" => $now,
        ":sId" => $id];//       ":lastV" => $now,
        $connection = connectToDB();
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $result = $statement->execute($import);
        $count = $statement->rowCount();

        if($count > 0)
        {
        }else
        {
            echo 'Failure';
        }

    }
```

The print is generated client-side after the document is loaded and an XHR to storePrint.php fires. In hopes that a record is updated, or in the event that that print OR sessionId don't already exist, creates a new record.  The problem is that both print or sessionId can change without the other changing.  I need to find a way (**using a single query if possible**) to check if either exist print, or sessionId.  If either exist, then update the others (print, lastVisited in the case we found a record with the same sessionId OR sessionId,lastVisited if we found a matching print). Someone has pointed out that I may have designed my table poorly for what I want to do. Updating causes integrity constraint violations. So lost... I made id Primary with auto increment, and print unique and sessionId unique.  Please shove me in the right direction.  The other queries I attempted to use were:

```
INSERT INTO prints (print, sessionId, lastUpdated) VALUES (:print,:sid,:lastC) CASE WHEN print <> :print THEN :print ELSE print END, last_update = CASE WHEN print <> :print THEN :lastV ELSE lastUpdated END;
```

```
INSERT INTO prints (print,sessionId,lastUpdated) VALUES (:print,:sid,:lastC) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE print = CASE print WHEN <> THEN :print, ELSE print END, sessionId = CASE sessionId WHEN <> :sid THEN :sid ELSE sessionId END, lastUpdated=now()
```

and

```
INSERT INTO prints (print, sessionId, lastUpdated) VALUES (:print, :sid, :lastC) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE     lastUpdated = CASE WHEN print <> :print THEN :lastC ELSE lastUpdated END, print = CASE WHEN print <> :print THEN :print ELSE print END
```

I found that using PDO's prepared statements and using VALUE() was causing me a syntax issue as it would escape already escaped strings turning them into-> VALUES(''88fe273778rs8s...'') at which point I went back to the first prepared statement, and came here for direction...
[image: The table structure]

[image: Contents of the table]

**So finally, do I rewrite the query, redesign the table, or both???**

UPDATE:
  The actual problem I am encountering, is a integrity constraint violation on my sessionId column. I end up with a collision where the print matches `WHERE id=1` and the sessionId matches `WHERE id=14`  MySQL decides it is going to update `id=1` and causes integrity constraint due to duplicate sessionId.  **How do I use `CASE` to `DELETE` the other matching record rows?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are working too hard.  Won't this do what you desire?

```
INSERT INTO prints (print,sessionId,lastUpdated)
      VALUES (:print,:sid,:lastC)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
           print = VALUES(print),
           sessionId = VALUES(sId),
           lastUpdated = VALUES(lastV)
```

But...  Which column is `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`)?  IODKU needs such to know when it is a "duplicate".

Let's say it is `print`.  If so, then `print = VALUES(print)` is not needed.

Comment: id is the ```PRIMARY``` Key, sessionId, and print are both seperately ```UNIQUE```

Comment: It is rare for a table to have two unique keys; 3 is probable "wrong".

Comment: I want to ensure that I don't assign a print to a dup sessionId.  As they travel throughout the page, or other sites, their prints are updated to a different hash.  Sometimes when a visitor re-enters the site cold, they are assigned a print that doesn't match print from immediate previous visit, but a prev print that they had during a diff visit, with a diff sessionId.  The fubar comes when that occurs and the server hands out the existing sessionId AGAIN, (which is normal and expected behaviour, right?) So now, I have a print matching @ ```id=1``` and a sessionId matching at ```id=19```

Comment: Can I write my query to check for this, or should I be checking through php, with additional querys run prior to inserting/updating the table?

Comment: So, maybe the pair `(print, sessionid)` is "unique"?  If they are individually unique, then a user can print only once per session id??